# Diagnose my PC that randomly shuts down

Tags: windows-8, crash, diagnostic

My PC randomly shuts down. This happens even if I am just leave it on at the desktop without any major applications running.

I was wondering if anyone knows how I could go about diagnosing the problem?

PC specs:
Windows 8.1
AMD 6300
8 GB RAM
GTX 970

At first, I thought the PC might be overheating. All the fans are spinning. It doesn't seem hot. Also it shuts down even when idle. I did a clean reinstall of Windows and it still shuts down randomly.

I am happy to buy whatever I need to fix the problem; the main issue is that I don't know how to figure out what is wrong!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the wattage of your power supply? Also, does it blue screen or just turn off as if it were losing power?

Comment: check the steps from this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2028504

Comment: @cascer1 the power supply is 500W. I used to have a HD 7850, but maybe the new GPU merits a more powerfuly power supply?

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the link. I will try this shortly

Comment: What was the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding the OS itself (you can run linux stress test or whatever to
eliminate that) start with a PSU.

It might be defective OR it might claim to produce more wattage than it actually does resulting in shutdown.

A second suspect would be memory I guess.

A distant(?) third would be the motherboard I guess.

Swap components one at a time to discover what the issue is.

Did you monitor the cpu, northbridge and case temperatures?
Though I'm not aware of northbridge being the culprit since the 865 chipset days where you had to tinker with the stock northbridge cooler.